# Keyboard with 99% numbers and 1% letters

Tags: android, keyboard

I have a listview with a lot (59) Edittext. 99% of times, the user will introduce number, but some rare times, he will need to introduce alfanumeric characters.

I tried this solution I see here, but in my Samsung s3mini and s4, it doesn't work...

```
holder.valor.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

What is the best way to do it??? 
If possible, I would prefere not to add buttons to choose keyboard in my UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they're allowed to input text, why are you setting the InputType to `TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER`?

```
holder.valor.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

or just set the XML attribute:

```
android:inputType="text"
```